# How to extract authentication and authorization modules from OpenAm

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, openam

There are many modules in OpenAm
what if I  just want to use authentication\authorization modules

So I wonder how to extract authentication and authorization modules from OpenAm and make the modules work functionally?

Does anyone have some thoughts?

Any tips would be appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authentication modules are quite easy to extract, however they are very much tied to the whole authentication framework, hence probably it will be very difficult to use it for your personal needs. In the Maven project see the openam-authentication submodule.

Most likely the situation will be the same for the authorization code as well, that code is mainly in openam-entitlements and openam-core modules.